# How to find OneDrive Item Id associated with Microsoft SharePoint Document

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, onedrive, spfx

I’m trying to use the Excel Graph API in JavaScript to update an Excel file stored in SharePoint. From what I can see I need the OneDrive ID of the Document to do this.

https://graph.microsoft.com/{version}/me/drive/items/{id}/workbook/

I have all the SharePoint metadata from the SpHttpClient, how do I get the OneDrive ID ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally got this figured thanks to [Toni Pohl](https://blog.atwork.at/post/Access-files-in-OneDrive-or-SharePoint-with-Microsoft-Graph-and-the-Excel-API)

If you have the SharePoint URL just replace the /list with /drives to get the OneDrive stuff.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxxx.sharepoint.com:/sites/yyyy:/lists?$select=name,id 
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxxx.sharepoint.com:/sites/yyyy:/drives?$select=name,id
```

get

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.list)(name,id)",
    "value": [

        {
            "@odata.etag": "\"57583463-1579-4237-a909-2f99727b188a,5\"",
            "id": "57583463-1579-4237-a909-2f99727b188a",
            "name": "Shared Documents"
        },
        {
            "@odata.etag": "\"4c00f5ba-2e73-475a-b027-ae1597bf16ab,7\"",
            "id": "4c00f5ba-2e73-475a-b027-ae1597bf16ab",
            "name": "DocumentTemplates"
        },       
    ]
}
```

and OneDrive

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives(name,id)",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "b!5V21gHgALUSQCeWNdx-VSP8SCmeUW3dHqSOlJMbYv2RjNFhXeRU3QqkJL5lyexiK",
            "name": "Documents"
        },
        {
            "id": "b!5V21gHgALUSQCeWNdx-VSP8SCmeUW3dHqSOlJMbYv2S69QBMcy5aR7AnrhWXvxar",
            "name": "DocumentTemplates"
        },

    ]
}
```

For crying in a bucket Microsoft!!! Why is this not Documented.

Comment: Why is it easier to find this info from blogs instead of official docs? Thanks for sharing Toni's article with your answer here, it helped me understand how this API works way better than the official docs, unfortunately